# Spring XD Kafka source doesn't register as a consumer?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-xd

After deploying the following Spring XD stream:

"kafka --topics=rm-sdrs --outputType=text/plain --zkconnect=hw1-vapp033:2181 | file --dir=/tmp/myfile --name=all_sdrs"

I would expect to see a new consumer on kafka topic "rm-sdrs", but see nothing on Zookeeper:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 14] ls /consumers
[]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 15]
```

is that expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for using Spring XD!

Just as a clarification: the Spring XD Kafka source is not using the high level consumer (it is based on the simple consumer API), therefore is not registering in Zookeeper.

Hope this helps,
Marius

Comment: But it means I can't use kafka monitoring tools (e.g kafka-manager) to monitor topics and their consumers. Is there a good alternative? My goal is to monitor the ingestion rate and consuming rate and whether there are any lag.

Comment: We do not use the high level consumer due to its numerous issues and limitations - which are pretty much captured here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Client+Re-Design. That being said, version 1.3 of Spring XD to be released by the end of November will support offset management via native Kafka topic support. If 'kafka-manager' relies on monitoring high level consumers exclusively, I would suggest trying out https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor which supports monitoring the 0.8.2 kafka offset management topic.